# How to get the biggest suported picture size in device?

Tags: android, camera, resolution, image

I want to take a photo using `SurfaceView` and `PictureCallBack` with the highest resolution supported.

Here is the configuration that works for my Galaxy Nexus:

```
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Supported Sizes: " + sizes,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    params.setPictureSize(2592, 1944);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);

    camera.setParameters(params);
```

The 2592 x 1944, is the best resolution for my device, but how I get from the `var sizes` the highest resolution for any devices?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How about you sort the supported picture sizes? It's up to you to then determine the criteria. I.e. you could sort on the width first, and then the height. Alternatively, multiply width and height (as that will give you to total number of pixels/'highest resolution') and use that for sorting. In both cases it'll be easiest to use `Collections.sort(...)` with your own `Comparator<Camera.Size>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through your list, and multiply the height and width to get the pixel count and keep a variable of the largest index

```
int max = 0;
int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++){
     Size s = List.get(i);
     int size = s.height * s.width;
     if (size > max) {
         index = i;
         max = size;
     }
}
params.setPictureSize(List.get(index).width, List.get(index).height);
```

Comment: This worked fine, but I took off the `()` from `width` and `height` for exemple: `params.setPictureSize(List.get(index).width, List.get(index).height);`